# Firemonkey open local file iOS by default application

Tags: ios, file, delphi, firemonkey

Delphi 10.4.1
iOS 14.2

I have found different sources, but they do not work. Like this:

```
URL       : NSUrl;
URL := TNSURL.Wrap(TNSURL.OCClass.fileURLWithPath(StrToNSStr( ExtractFileName(AFileName) )));
if SharedApplication.canOpenURL(URL) then
    SharedApplication.openURL(URL);
```

URL have a valid data like:  file:///var/ ......  and i can open it by

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate( NSUrlToStr(URL) );
```

but SharedApplication.openURL(URL); do nothing.

May be some true work example with TUIDocumentInteractionController ?

Any complete working example?

1. File exist.
2. I need write some to  info.plist.TemplateiOS.xml ?
3. I need open it in default application (file can be .doc, .jpg, .pdf,  etc)

Comment: For point 1: your method is the same as the one I use, so that part should be fine. Are you sure you specify the correct path? For point 2: The template is not available on iOS, it is only used by Delphi to generate the final info.plist, which you cannot edit.

Comment: 1. Yes. I got valid path, because i can use code like this: WebBrowser1.Navigate( NSUrlToStr(URL) ); and work fine (for JPG and PDF)